# C# fill out side of a polygon

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, polygon

In c# I can fill a polygon in a bitmap image as following.

```
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.FillPolygon(colorBrush, points.ToArray());
        }
```

[image: After Using FillPolygon()]

`FillPolygon` method fills the pixels inside the polygon, in this case, the white pixels and the black pixels remains the same.

Now, I want just the opposite of this operation. That means, exterior pixels will be filled and interior pixels will remain the same. I this case, black pixels are exterior pixels.

**Edit**
I need this because let's say, I have a binary image of an object. I need to clip the pixels with background color(black) and the pixels inside the white polygon will remain unchanged.

Comment: You could do a 2-pass action. Meaning first pass, create this bitmap. second pass: fill the pixel in other bitmap when the pixel in the generated bitmap is black.

Comment: Anything wrong with using a white background and filling the polygon black?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you can try including the corners of the bitmap in your polygon points. If it works, it will have the effect of everything within the polygon becoming outside, and will produce the same result.

Comment: Here, just consider that white pixels are the pixels, I can not change. Now I need to replace the pixels outside a polygon with a specific color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a `GraphicsPath` as follows:

1. Add the polygon to the path.
2. Add a rectangle to the path which encompasses the area you want to "invert".
3. Use `Graphics.FillPath()` to fill the path.

For an example program, create a default Windows Forms app and override `OnPaint()` as follows:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    var points = new []
    {              
        new PointF(150, 250),
        new PointF( 50, 500),
        new PointF(250, 400),
        new PointF(300, 100),
        new PointF(500, 500),
        new PointF(500,  50),
    };

    using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        path.AddPolygon(points);

        // Uncomment this to invert:
        // p.AddRectangle(this.ClientRectangle);

        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
        }
    }
}
```

If you run that (and resize the window) you'll see a black shape inside a white window.

Uncomment the indicated line and run the program and you'll see a white shape inside a black window (i.e. adding the `ClientRectangle` inverted it).

Comment: exactly what I needed. Works out of the box. Thanks.